# How to use fprint fingerprint scanner C library with Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk

I need to compile and utilize the fprint C library https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/tree/master
to be able to use it on a Specialized Android(API level 17) based Fingerprint Reader Device, however the library doesn't have any JNI, any CMakeList.txt or Android.mk files as specified in Android NDK documentation.

I have tried to create my own CMakelist.txt and Android.mk files for this library, these haven't worked, probably because there is no JNI at all and no android.mk files in the sub-modules of the library, the actually file that is supposed to carry out the operations is a header file, and not a C file that can be imported to android. This is it below from the library: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/blob/master/libfprint/fprint.h

I have tried some other libraries, I tried using SourceAFI api, but that doesn't support API 17 android devices, I saw a fork of the library that did, but it takes about 90secs to complete the matching process.

I am seeking any pathway to a solution or an alternative native library capable of carrying out finger print scanning and verification that is Android compatible. Whatever would require less work to make it functional for my project.